# Jquery get value using class name

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of an input text field(price) and multiply it by quantity and do some deduction and display on total column.`((price * quantity) - credit)`

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j6BF/1/)

How can i get each quantity values in above fiddle ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `tr` of the current `.total` and then find the `.quantity` element within it

```
    $('.total').text(function () {
        var q = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').text()
        var credit = $(this).prev().text();
        q = q.replace(/,/g, '');
        p = p.replace(/,/g, '');
        credit = credit.replace(/,/g, '');                

        tot = ((parseFloat(p) * parseFloat(q)) - (parseFloat(credit)));
        tot = Math.floor(tot*100)/100;
        return tot.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3wCkU/)